# modify a value into an external access form using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two access databases, A and B.
Into A I have a hidden form that is always loaded. INto In this hidden form there are several controls (text box).
DataBase A calls a code that runs into database B.
What I want is that when the code into database B ends, it has to write a value into the hidden form in Database A.
Could someone support me somehow?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Edit question to post DataBase A procedure. Maybe you should just add a last line like `Forms!formname!fieldname = something`. Do you want to replace a value in record?

Comment: NO, I want to store a value, generated in Db A into a form belong DB B. The problem is that I cannot understand how to refer to DB B, in other words how I can access DB B from DB A using Forms!formname!fieldname= something from DB a.

Answer (score 0):

Your question narrative says 'write a value into the hidden form in Database A' then your comment indicates the reverse. If I understand correctly, DB A is open and calls code in DB B and you want DB B to set a value on form in DB A. Consider:

```
Dim db As Access.Application
Set db = GetObject("your path to database A")
db.Forms("formname").textboxname = something
```